# How to extract a single property of the posted JSON in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, model-binding

Consider this posted JSON:

```
{
   name: 'John',
   age: 38,
   biography: 'something about john here'
}
```

and this C# class:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Now, in my API I want to read that `biography` too. I can't change the `Person` class:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(Person person)
{
   // here name and age are bound,
   // how can I retrieve the value of `biography`?
}
```

Please note that I can't change `Person` class. I know I can create a new `Person` class to facilitate binding, but I wonder if it can be done without creating the new class.

Comment: Add it as a header. Override your submit function (event.preventDefault();), add the header value, then submit the form

Answer (score 3):

Without creating a new class, you can also directly filter data from the Request body, check the following code:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ToDoController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost("CreatePerson")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateAsync()
    { 
        string json; 
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8))
            json = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

        var jobect = JObject.Parse(json);

        var person = new Person();
        person.Name = jobect.GetValue("Name") != null ? jobect.GetValue("Name").ToString() : "";
        person.Age = jobect.GetValue("Age") != null ? Convert.ToInt32(jobect.GetValue("Age")): 0;

        var biography = jobect.GetValue("biography") != null ? jobect.GetValue("biography").ToString() : "";

        return Ok(biography);
    }
}
```

The result as below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried your method, and I recieved this error: `The input does not contain any JSON tokens. Expected the input to start with a valid JSON token, when isFinalBlock is true. LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0`

Answer (score 1):

Just extend the `Person` class:

```cs
public class PersonWithBiography : Person
{
    public string Biography { get; set; }
}

...

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(PersonWithBiography person)
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do net want to create new class, you can send your data as `IFormCollection` to the endpoint and read it like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(IFormCollection formData)
{
   string biography = formData["biography"]
}
```

Personally I'd just go with a new `PersonWithBio` class, that extends `Person`.